# How to reload the whole page in Liferay

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, liferay, reload

I am using Liferay 5.2.3.

In my `view.jsp` file I have a hidden form that after it is populated, it is sent to the `processAction(request, response)` method of my portlet like this:

```
document.getElementById('email').value = member.emailAddress;
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

After all the java code in my extended `GenericPortlet` class from `processAction(request, response)` has been executed, I want my entire web page to be refreshed, not only the portlet.

I think there are two ways to do that:
1: inside `processAction`
2: using some kind of ajax code and call `document.location.reload()` after `document.getElementById('myForm').submit();`

Could you share some sample code for any of these options (or others)?

Comment: separate from the answer: Please do yourself a favour and consider upgrading. This version is now unmaintained for several years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing the default behaviour in portal world: After triggering an Action, the whole page will be reloaded. Whatever you did in order to work around this default: Undo it and you're done.

Look at (almost) any of the Liferay demo portlets, e.g. on https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets